# How to adjust setOnErrorListener in my mediaplayer and set status as "offline" in textview

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

When my url is not working i need to adjust an Error listener which sets the offline status in textview . I don't know how to adjust this exactly . Or what does return false means? Any help will be gratefull .
Here is my media player:

lv_tracks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {


        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            mSelectedTrackTitle.setText(stations[position]);
            // mSelectedTrackImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
            nowplaying.setText("Now Playing");
            mPlayerControl.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_filled);
            Resources res = getResources();
            String[] links = res.getStringArray(R.array.links);
            String url = links[position];
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,url,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                Log.d("abc", "playing and now going to reset : " + url);
                try {
                    mMediaPlayer.pause();
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
                    mMediaPlayer.release();
                    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    nowplaying.setText("Offline");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"SERVER IS DOWN",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //mMediaPlayer.release();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                try {
                    Log.d("abc", "in else part :" + url);
                    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mMediaPlayer.start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    nowplaying.setText("Offline");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"SERVER IS DOWN",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //mMediaPlayer.release();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return;
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Logcat (when i first select):

> 10-12 17:07:54.426 20080-20091/indusradio.pk W/MediaPlayer-JNI:
>   MediaPlayer finalized without being released 10-12 17:07:54.426
>   20080-20091/indusradio.pk I/MediaPlayerNative: Pid:20080 MediaPlayer
>   destructor 10-12 17:08:29.478 20080-20096/indusradio.pk
>   D/MediaPlayerNative: Message: MEDIA_ERROR(100),
>   ext1=MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN(1), ext2=0x80000000 10-12 17:08:29.480
>   20080-20096/indusradio.pk E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
>   10-12 17:08:29.480 20080-20096/indusradio.pk D/MediaPlayerNative:
>   [notify] : [1204] callback app listenerNotNull=1, send=0 10-12
>   17:08:29.487 20080-20080/indusradio.pk D/HwRTBlurUtils: check blur
>   style for HwToast-Toast, themeResId : 0x7f0900b4, context :
>   com.example.maham.indusradio.MainActivity@77db462, Nhwext : 6, get
>   Blur : disable with ,
>   android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable@c363c7 10-12 17:08:29.505
>   20080-20080/indusradio.pk W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Prepare
>   failed.: status=0x1 10-12 17:08:29.506 20080-20080/indusradio.pk
>   W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
>   10-12 17:08:29.507 20080-20080/indusradio.pk W/System.err:     at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1313) 10-12
>   17:08:29.507 20080-20080/indusradio.pk W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.maham.indusradio.MainActivity$3.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:174)

It crashes sometimes and took time for about 20secs to display offline status.

Comment: can't you check your url for connectivity before assinging it to media player?

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: `True if the method handled the error, false if it didn't. Returning false, or not having an OnErrorListener at all, will cause the OnCompletionListener to be called.` from [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener)

Comment: mediaplayer.onprepare() is crashing because url is not working. How can i check my url before?

Comment: Mediaplayer is built such way that it should handle broken url. Anyway what do you want to check? Can you post your `onprepared` function also? I guess media player will not call `onprepared` callback if url is broken.

Comment: try calling your setOnErrorListener above setDataSource(url) function

Comment: @MushahidGillani I've tried this but no .

Comment: share the exception ? you can set your text in catch also.just give it a try

Comment: @MushahidGillani It Works :D

Comment: @MushahidGillani post it as an answer Please!

Comment: please also share your exception in which you are getting in logcat also. it will be helpful for tracing the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set text in a catch like

```java
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);

    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                     mMediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });

    mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public boolean 
    onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        });

        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                      nowplaying.setText("OFFLINE")
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```

Comment: But the problem is it still stops the app.

Comment: also call mMediaPlayer.release() in catch

Comment: and please share you error or warning. can not help with out it. check your logcat and share the exception you are getting

Comment: When i call mMediaPlayer.release(); it is crashing on mMediaplayer.prepare();

Comment: remove mMediaPlayer.release() and run the app when it crashes do share your exception/error

Comment: share your logs in your question not in my answer :) first remove  mMediaPlayer.release() in a catch then run your app when it crashes then share the logs thanks

Comment: sorry about that it was by mistake . 
I have removed .release(); .
but when i select the item from my list with dead url twice then it crashes . At first it runs well . But on the second time after playing working url it crashes. 
I will update my question.

Comment: what is the status of text when you select the first item ?

Comment: it says "NOW PLAYING"

Comment: may be i can't help you here. you need to set break points and debug whats the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181804/discussion-between-mushahid-gillani-and-maham).

Comment: It's okay i think it is crashing only sometimes so no problem . Other times it works fine.